# Is there any quality difference in image captured using camera.takePicture(shutter callback, jpeg callback) and setOneShotPreviewCallback

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm an intermediate android programmer. I've a simple application created for learning camera. My app is using `camera.takePicture()` method to register callbacks for JPEG callback and eventually capture the picture.
But I feel that it may also be possible to capture the image using `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` and providing a callback.

My question is:

- Will there be any differences in image quality between the 2 approaches?
- Any additional things to be taken care of when trying to construct image using `setOneShotPreviewCallback()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takePicture()` uses (potentially) the camera's full resolution. The preview gives you the image shown on screen which is more usually the screen's resolution. The picture will be higher resolution in general and higher quality. Note that you get something like JPEG-encoded data from the picture callback, but raw image buffer data in the preview callback.

Answer (score -1):

The person is using the surface view to capture the image by camera its quality will be good